# PHP - Redirecting into another page

Tags: php, redirect

```
header("Location:post.php?id=120");
```

This is the method which i am using now to pass values between two pages.
This is not a secure way.
Instead of that i want to use "post" method of sending values while redirecting.
Is there any equivalent way to "post" in PHP ?
I am looking at alternate ways to do this (since not secure)

Comment: POST is no more secure than GET. Can you elaborate what exactly you mean by "secure" - secure against what/whom?

Comment: What is insecure here? Showing id in URL?

Comment: i dont want to show the id in URL, in a small case, it probably doesnt matter,this is an example, but in my code i am putting in some private data, how do i make sure it doesnt show up in the URL?

Comment: To hide data the effective way is to bind your data into sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres nothing insecure about passing an id between pages. That actually quite common and is even done here on SO.

If you're horribly worried about users seeing the id, why not save your id on a session variable? That way its a little more hidden.

Answer (score 0):

To send POST, maybe it's easiest to make a form with a hidden input field with a value you want: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="120" />` and just post the form to the `post.php`. Of course, this is not any more secure from the previous method unless you do some validating, escaping, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Standard "POST" request is not more secure than "GET" one. It just hides parameters/data to the user and gives you the impression of security. You still need to check validity of Id in your logic (is the ID valid? is the user granted to access this data?).

May be you can try to:

- create token with unique id (GUID?)
- put "id" in Server session, with token as identifier
- redirect the user with `header("Location:post.php?id=".$myToken);`
- in "post.php", load data from Server session and destroy entry to clean up memory

User will still be able to see data (the token), but this token will be invalidated as soon as page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You are *probably* looking for the [sessions](http://php.net/session).
"Probably" because there is nothing certain in your question to give you a more relevant answer.

However, you shouldn't use sessions to pass variables like id which is obviously identifies the destination page.

Answer (score 0):

Use JS to send a post request in AJAX. Im pretty sure thats what you need...

Answer (score -2):

You can store variables in session and then make redirection (this is safe way)

- http://php.net/manual/pl/features.sessions.php

Or make HTML redirection

```
<form method="post" action="post.php" name="redirection">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="120"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){document.forms.redirection.submit();});
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe do it via cURL and then redirect. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php